# Нестандартный input: дата и месяц

Tags: javascript, html, form, input, datetime

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сверстать такой инпут:[image]

Стандартный тип date предлагает формат: дата.месяц.год.

Я так понимаю, здесь нужно задать инпуту тип number и возможность ввести два двузначных числа, разделённых автоматически подставляемых слешем. При этом обоим числам должны быть заданы диапазоны, и второе число должно распознаваться как невалидное, в зависимости от первого, поскольку в разных месяцах разное количество дней.

Для меня это сложная задача в нескольких аспектах.

1. Как подставить автоматический слеш?
2. Как сделать, чтобы в одно поле вводилось два числа, и распознавались они тоже как два числа, а не как одно?
3. Как настроить зависимость между первым и вторым числами?

Answer (score 1):

На инпут вешаете обработчик на ввод с клавиатуры.
В нем проверяете количество введенных символов, думаю можно сделать валидацию, отсеять буквы, спецсимволы и пробелы. После ввода двух цифр, можно добавить автоматом слеш, просто к строке + "/" и вернуть, или привоить инпуту, ну и дальше еще две цифры также. Можно слеш попробовать сделать через css с помощью :after

Comment: Спасибо, я попробую! Уже понятнее выглядит.

Answer (score 1):

Нашла более простое решение: регулярные выражения через свойство pattern. Хотя слеш тут нужно ставить вручную, и зависимость второго числа от первого не устанавливается, можно очень легко добиться более-менее приемлемого эффекта.
http://html5pattern.com/